# Ускорение цикла

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация, инспекция-кода, производительность

Очень медленная скорость 3d цикла: 43 с. Можно ли заметно ускорить такой код?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants
import time

start_time = time.time()

c = scipy.constants.c #speed of light

N = 1024
Nx = 128
Ny = 128
x_size = 50
y_size = 50
U = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=complex)

fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )

for k in range( N ):
    for i in range( Nx ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U[k, i, j] = 1 - ((c * fx[i] / nu[k]) ** 2) - ((c * fy[j] / nu[k]) ** 2 )

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: это случаем, не LU разложение?

Comment: Откуда задачка? Что за численный метод? Или qr? Очень похоже

Comment: Кажется, что у Вас есть проблема в постановке задачи, так как процесс не сходится

Comment: вроде к LU или qr это не имеет отношения, по крайней мере я на это не ориентировался. Это кусок просто чтобы на двумерной сетке fx,fy, прогнав ее по одномерной сетке nu получить трехмерный массив.

Comment: Почитайте мой ответ. Ваш процесс не сходится.

Comment: Порядки числа у меня очень большие, это из-за того, что я не прикрутил тут нормировки к величинам. Константа должна быть c = scipy.constants.c *1e-9, тогда норма выходит 2.039590718538875e-12. Другого объяснения не вижу, матрицы вроде выглядят одинаково

Comment: Вам подходит моё решение?

Comment: Да, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Примите ответ (=

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Ускорение в 430 раз

**Задача поставлена некорректно**

Мне удалось добиться решения за **0.07 секунды** с помощью оптимизации вычислений и алгоритмизации.

Сразу следует отметить, что данный процесс не сходится и для различных оптимизаций мы можем получить очень сильные вариации. Это связано с неустойчивостью численного решения, который приводит автор. В частности, для конечного решения это означает, что математические действия над данным выражениям могут носить фатальный характер и конечный результат будет очень сильно меняться. Пример детальный разбор представлен последним пунктом.

## 1

Во-первых, перенесите начало отсчёта на момент "перед циклом" (в вашем случае, это ничего не изменит, конечно, но, всё-таки)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants
import time

c = scipy.constants.c #speed of light

N = 1024
Nx = 128
Ny = 128
x_size = 50
y_size = 50
U = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=complex)

fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )


start_time = time.time()
for k in range( N ):
    for i in range( Nx ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U[k, i, j] = 1 - ((c * fx[i] / nu[k]) ** 2) - ((c * fy[j] / nu[k]) ** 2 )

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

## 2

Всё сильно зависит от вашего процессора. Например, у меня получается 30 секунд.

## 3

1024 * 128 * 128 -- это не то чтобы очень мало. 16 млн. Кажется, что 30 секунд вполне разумная цена. Более того, внутри цикла, у вас есть довольно тяжёлые операции

## 4

Если хотите ускорения, то давайте оптимизируем цикл:

```
c2 = c ** 2
for k in range( N ):
    nu_k2 = nu[k] ** 2
    for i in range( Nx ):
        fx_i = fx[i] ** 2
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U[k, i, j] = 1 - c2 / nu_k2 * (fx_i + ((fy[j]) ** 2 ))
```

Основная оптимизация происходит за счёт того, что мы не будем повторно вычислять значения. Таким образом, после того, как мы вынесли `nu_k2` и `fx_i`, получаем 18 секунд.

Откажемся от деления на каждом шаге:

```
c2 = c ** 2
for k in range( N ):
    nu_k2 = nu[k] ** 2
    d = c2 / nu_k2
    for i in range( Nx ):
        fx_i = fx[i] ** 2
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U[k, i, j] = 1 - d * (fx_i + (fy[j]) ** 2 )
```

и получим прирост ещё в 1-2 секунды.

Так как numpy написан на `C`, то можем сделать следующее:

```
fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx ) ** 2
fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny ) ** 2
nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )

c2 = c ** 2
for k in range( N ):
    nu_k2 = nu[k] ** 2
    d = c2 / nu_k2
    for i in range( Nx ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U[k, i, j] = 1 - d * (fx[i] + fy[j])
```

Сократим расходы до 13 секунд.

## 6 (0.07 секунды)

Финальное решение. Вынесем общую подматрицу в предподсчёт и будем её переиспользовать. И, наконец, **0.07 секунды**

```
a = np.zeros((fx.shape[0], fy.shape[0]))
for i in range( Nx ):
    for j in range( Ny ):
        a[i, j] = fx[i] + fy[j]

c2 = c ** 2
for k in range( N ):
    nu_k2 = nu[k] ** 2
    d = c2 / nu_k2
    U[k, :, :] = 1 - d * a
```

## 7

Запишем проверку, которая покажет, что решения идентичные

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants

c = scipy.constants.c #speed of light

N = 8
Nx = 4
Ny = 4
x_size = 50
y_size = 50
U = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=complex)

fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )


for k in range( N ):
    for i in range( Nx ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U[k, i, j] = 1 - ((c * fx[i] / nu[k]) ** 2) - ((c * fy[j] / nu[k]) ** 2 )

U0 = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=complex)

c2 = c ** 2
fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx ) ** 2
fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny ) ** 2
nu=c2 / np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N ) ** 2

a = np.zeros((fx.shape[0], fy.shape[0]))
for i in range( Nx ):
    for j in range( Ny ):
        a[i, j] = fx[i] + fy[j]


for k in range(N):
    for i in range( Nx ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U0[k, :, :] = 1 - nu[k] * a

print(abs(U0 - U).sum())
```

Норма равно `0.01`

## 8

Далее, более формально можно привести к матричному виду и ещё ускорить. Но это уже совсем другая задача.

## Анализ сходимости

Рассмотрим небольшие начальные данные. Сделаем простое преобразование. В результирующей формуле вынесем минус за скобки. Тогда получим выражение:

```
1 - ((c * fx[i] / nu[k]) ** 2) + ((c * fy[j] / nu[k]) ** 2 )
```

Итоговый код, который сравивает получающиеся решения:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants
import time

c = scipy.constants.c #speed of light

N = 64
Nx = 32
Ny = 32
x_size = 50
y_size = 50
U = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=complex)

fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )


for k in range( N ):
    for i in range( Nx ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            U[k, i, j] = 1 - ((c * fx[i] / nu[k]) ** 2) - ((c * fy[j] / nu[k]) ** 2 )

U0 = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=complex)

fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )


for k in range( N ):
    for i in range( Nx ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            x = ((c * fx[i] / nu[k]) ** 2) + ((c * fy[j] / nu[k]) ** 2 )
            U0[k, i, j] = 1 - x

print(abs(U0 - U).sum())
```

Если мы посмотрим на результат, то заметим, что исходное решение и предложенное отличается на `1058`. Таким образом, делаем вывод, что данный процесс не сходится. И здесь вопрос к автору. Что это за задача

Comment: можно ещё заранее получить `range(N)`, `range(Nx)`, `range(Ny)`. прирост минимальный, но тоже немного оптимизация ;)

Comment: @Александр range(N) возвращает генератор. Поэтому ни на что не влияет

Comment: время на создание `range` крошечное, но факт - создание `range` будет чуть дольше, чем использование готового, т.к. у нас очень много раз повторяется цикл, то немного это ускорит процесс +- 4 секунды, если учитывать создание всех `range` (1024 * 128 * 128 + 1024 * 128 + 1024)

Comment: проверь с созданием и использованием `range`, раз уж идём до конца

Comment: @Александр В `Python3` `range` натурально мгновенно инициализируется, нет в этом никакого смысла.

Comment: 0.07 без всех махинаций. Просто преобразорваниями

Comment: @hedgehogues, а как насчет еще заменить ```nu[k]**2``` на ```nu[k]*nu[k]```, это ведь еще быстрее будет

Comment: @n1tr0xs я думаю, что после такого прироста в производительности, дальнейшие оптимизации не нужны

Comment: вы сверили свой результат с первоначальным?
ну хотябы первый и последний элементы?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets да

Comment: @n1tr0xs да, действительно. Я сейчас всё перепроверяю

Comment: @n1tr0xs подозреваю, что проблема в сходимости. Хотя...

Comment: @hedgehogues как вариант можно проверить в каком именно пункте результат меняется так сильно, а из этого сделать выводы

Comment: @n1tr0xs так и делаю

Comment: @n1tr0xs добавил замечание по анализу сходимости.

Answer (score 5):

1. Зачем тип `complex`?? Не хочешь перейти на `float`? Тогда вычисления будут побыстрее  )
2. Оптимизируй цикл. Попробуй так:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import scipy.constants
   import time

   start_time = time.time()

   c = scipy.constants.c #speed of light

   N = 1024
   Nx = 128
   Ny = 128
   x_size = 50
   y_size = 50
   U = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=complex)

   c_fx_i_div_nu_k = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx), dtype=complex)
   c_fy_j_div_nu_k = np.zeros(shape=(N, Ny), dtype=complex)

   fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
   fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
   nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )

   c_div_nu = c / nu

   for k in range( N ):
       for i in range( Nx ):
           c_fx_i_div_nu_k[k,i] = (c_div_nu[k] * fx[i])**2

   for k in range( N ):
       for j in range( Ny ):
           c_fy_j_div_nu_k[k,j] = (c_div_nu[k] * fy[j])**2        

   for k in range( N ):
       for i in range( Nx ):
           for j in range( Ny ):
               U[k, i, j] = 1 - c_fx_i_div_nu_k[k,i] - c_fy_j_div_nu_k[k,j]

   print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
   ```

так более чем в 2 раза быстрее.
а насколько быстрее хочется?
в 10 раз?

тогда надо подумать о вычислениях на видеокарте или при помощи, многопоточности  ***numba***
Вот пример с ***float*** + ***numba***

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants
import time
import numba 

start_time = time.time()

@numba.njit
def calc():
    c = scipy.constants.c #speed of light

    N = 1024
    Nx = 128
    Ny = 128
    x_size = 50
    y_size = 50
    UU = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=np.float64)

    c_fx_i_div_nu_k = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx), dtype=np.float64)
    c_fy_j_div_nu_k = np.zeros(shape=(N, Ny), dtype=np.float64)

    fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
    fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
    nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )

    c_div_nu = c / nu

    for k in range( N ):
        for i in range( Nx ):
            c_fx_i_div_nu_k[k,i] = (c_div_nu[k] * fx[i])**2

    for k in range( N ):
        for j in range( Ny ):
            c_fy_j_div_nu_k[k,j] = (c_div_nu[k] * fy[j])**2        

    for k in range( N ):
        for i in range( Nx ):
            for j in range( Ny ):
                UU[k, i, j] = 1 - c_fx_i_div_nu_k[k,i] - c_fy_j_div_nu_k[k,j]
    return UU

U = calc()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print(U[3, 3, 3], U[-1, -1, -1])
```

но - проверь сам.  Правильно ли посчиталось... ))
numba - она такая...

На моем стареньком компьюторе получилось:

```
--- 1.2685229778289795 seconds ---
```

Что в 85 раз быстрее исходного варианта

Comment: У `Numba` не в видеокарте прикол, а в многопоточной обработке вычислений и других оптимизациях некоторых типовых конструкций.

Comment: @CrazyElf - исправлю

Answer (score 2):

Я просто добавил использование `Numba`. Она очень любит циклы в циклах в циклах. Результат не проверял.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import scipy.constants
import time

@nb.njit
def calc_loops():
    c = scipy.constants.c #speed of light

    N = 1024
    Nx = 128
    Ny = 128
    x_size = 50
    y_size = 50
    U = np.zeros(shape=(N, Nx, Ny), dtype=nb.types.complex128)

    fx=np.linspace( - Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx / ( 2 * x_size ), Nx )
    fy=np.linspace( - Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny / ( 2 * y_size ), Ny )
    nu=np.linspace( - x_size, x_size, N )

    for k in range( N ):
        for i in range( Nx ):
            for j in range( Ny ):
                U[k, i, j] = 1 - ((c * fx[i] / nu[k]) ** 2) - ((c * fy[j] / nu[k]) ** 2 )
    return U

start_time = time.time()
U = calc_loops()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Вывод:

```
--- 0.4318578243255615 seconds ---
```

Comment: Вы используете распараллеливание. Зачем. Можно без этого сделать быстрее.

Comment: @hedgehogues Да, последний ваш вариант супер )  Хотя хорошо бы проверить, что всё правильно считается

Comment: Возможно, косякнул. Но очень уж красиво получилось. Так что скорее всего всё ок.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Странно, у меня в U так `array([[[-1.17801639e+14+0.j, -1.15961102e+14+0.j, -1.14149781e+14+0.j,
         ..., -1.14149781e+14+0.j, -1.15961102e+14+0.j,
         -1.17801639e+14+0.j],
        [-1.15961102e+14+0.j, -1.14120566e+14+0.j, -1.12309244e+14+0.j,
         ...`

Comment: да, мой бок )

все работает

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь! Надо будет еще осмыслить все варианты, тем более что я буду на эти циклы еще накручивать операции, но последний с numba это то что надо. Я на такое ускорение как раз и рассчитывал, так как тот же кусок кода я считал ранее в пакете Матлаб и он давал как раз 0.5 секунды. По значениям у меня совпадает решения с ранее полученным. Не совсем понял про анализ сходимости, действительно странно что такая разница.